# issue on sending log to remote hadoop

Tags: hadoop

BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://192.168.1.9:9000/flume/test/FlumeData.1354578514087.tmp
2012-12-03 18:51:07,417 WARN hdfs.HDFSEventSink: HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create file/flume/test/FlumeData.1354578514087.tmp. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name node is in safe mode:

```
Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990
```

A ratio of 0.0000 usually indicates that none of your data nodes have come online, or are having connection issues between them and the name node. Suggest you check the logs for the data nodes